# Predis cluster slots manual set

Tags: redis, predis

is there any way in Predis to define the cluster slots manually when creating the instance in order to avoid the random server selection and getting the slots config so the request is directly sent to the right server at once making the process faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that using connection parameters:

```
$client = new Predis\Client([
    'tcp://node01?slots=0-5460',
    'tcp://node02?slots=5461-10922',
    'tcp://node03?slots=10923-16383',
], ['cluster' => 'redis']);
```

The "slots" connection parameter can accept a comma-separated list of single slots and ranges of contiguous slots, e.g.:

```
tcp://node01?slots=0,20-30,5461-10922
```

Comment: Hi, from what I tested... this is faster than letting Predis get the slots configuration, but not as fast as connecting to a cluster single node as a master to get the data directly from there (I know in advance the data is in that node). Any chance that Predis, knowing the slots in advance, can do a single connection (depending on the key CRC16) to improve speed? Thanks!

Comment: You may know the slot in advance, but not the node associated to it since redis-cluster can and will rebalance itself when needed. Even pre-configuring the slot map via connection parameters is actually a best-guess and it should be kept updated to be effective.

Comment: Maybe you could try with something like this https://gist.github.com/nrk/e1463f6c81f4f70427f9fab2ef202777

It's not tested as I'm going by memory but it should work, you basically configure the client with yout slot map, then you fetch the underlying connection to a specific slot and create a new client instance out of that connection instance. It's not really that different from what Predis already does internally though.